# How often should secrets be regenerated for token-authentication?

Tags: session-management

When implementing token-based authentication, is it recommended to regenerate secrets on a periodic basis? This is assuming the tokens generated have expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general guidelines here is; access to secret keys need to be highly restricted.  For example, if this is a hard-coded secret, then any time someone with access to source leaves the company, then the secrets need to be rotated. Clearly hard-coding secrets is bad practice, and if secrets were properly stored in an HSM/KSM/CloudHSM then there is less pressure to rotate. Keep in mind, [Yahoo stored the keys to the kingdom has a hard-coded secret in source control](https://www.engadget.com/2017/03/01/yahoo-hackers-accessed-32-million-accounts-with-forged-cookies/), so that anyone with access to source could then hijack 32 million email accounts (slow clap for the Yahoo security engineers).

tldr; rotate if you ever have reason to believe that the secret has been compromised.